# How can I make TO_DATE in Amazon Redshift work with multiple date formats in the same column?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datetime, amazon-redshift

I have a string column with date-time values that I need to convert into dates in order to calculate a dense rank.

This column can have any of the below 3 formats:

```sql
MM-DD-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
M-DD-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
MM-D-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
```

My SQL Statement to calculate the dense rank is based on this date-time column that I need to convert to date in order to rank descending:

```sql
DENSE_RANK() 
OVER (PARTITION by [columnA] ORDER BY
TO_DATE(SUBSTRING([dateColumn],0,8), 'MM-DD-YYYY') DESC)
```

However, I'm stuck with the `TO_DATE` function since I have three different formats in the same column.

How can I make TO_DATE in Amazon Redshift work with multiple date formats in the same column?

Comment: use charindex or position function to find the substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of using `SUBSTRING`, pass the entire date-time field to the [`TO_DATE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) function with the `MM-DD-YYYY` format which encapsulates all 3 formats above.**

Redshift has a strict mode that is turned off by default - `TO_DATE(string, format, is_strict=false)`. When not in strict mode, the time will automatically be discarded & Redshift is clever enough to infer how to convert the single digits to double digits.

The rest of your code can then work as per normal.

To demonstrate:

```sql
--MM-DD-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
SELECT TO_DATE('05-15-2022 4:12:34 PM','MM-DD-YYYY');
--M-DD-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
SELECT TO_DATE('4-01-2022 8:45:06 PM','MM-DD-YYYY');
--MM-D-YYYY H:MM:SS PM
SELECT TO_DATE('04-9-2022 6:23:10 PM','MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Output:

```sql
2022-05-15
2022-04-01
2022-04-09
```

In your case, this should work:

```sql
DENSE_RANK()
OVER (partition BY [columnA] ORDER BY 
TO_DATE(datecolumn, 'MM-DD-YYYY') DESC)
```

---

*P.S. To begin with, these dates should all be in the same format.*

*If you are responsible for producing the data, please only output dates in one format moving forward to make everyone's lives' much easier!*